# Responsive Media Query for a Submenu

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm learning Responsive Media Query, I would like to do two things:

1. Remove arrow icon
2. Adapt the submenu, I guess I just have to decrease the font size?

Here is an illustration below:

[image]

How to remove this icon, please?

HTML

```
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index" [class.active]="menu.active">
    <ng-container>
      <a class="item" (click)="selectMenu(menu)">
        <i [class]="menu.iconClass"></i>
        <span class="links_name">{{ menu.name }}</span>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
      </a>
      <ul
        class="submenu"
        #submenu
        [ngStyle]="{ 'height': menu.active ? submenu.scrollHeight + 'px' : 0 + 'px' } "
      >
        <li *ngFor="let submenu of menu.submenu">
          <a routerLink="{{ submenu.url }} "
            ><span class="links_subname">{{ submenu.name }}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/* Responsive Media Query */

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .sidebar {
        width: 0;
    }
    .sidebar.active {
        width: 60px;
    }
    .home-section {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .sidebar.active~.home-section {
        left: 60px;
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
    }
    .home-section nav {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
    .sidebar .logo-details .logo_name img {
        height: 30px;
        width: 65px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .sidebar.active~.home-section nav {
        left: 60px;
        width: calc(100% - 60px);
    }
    .sidebar .nav-links .submenu .links_subname {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Here is a reproduction [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cdyhsj?file=src/styles.css).

Thank you for your help and comments.

Comment: Also learn to write media queries for large screens instead. let me explain. Consider using a mobile first approach when coding or implementing UIs. Like start with writing the HTML and CSS of what it will look like on mobile. So that the media queries you will be adding are min-width media queries. That is how the site will look like on tablet or desktop widths. This way, you will rarely run into responsive design problems

Comment: @Obumuneme Nwabude, Yes, I don't want the icons to display. For the Submenu, I don't know what to do... I would like some simple things for the user, but I have no idea actually??

Comment: sorry for deleting my comment, Its now I understand well. using display:none can remove the icons, I have forked your stackblitz and I'm editing it, will post it. But then for the submenu, I think you have to leave it that way, maybe  when in mobile, you instead show an overlay, like a darker cover, over the home-section, so that the user can focus on the sidebar they just opened. Because the submenu and sidebar text are useful to mobile users too. or am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: also you can move the styles in styles.css to app.component.css okay, so that styles.css doesn't get very long

Comment: someone has answered something valuable already, maybe no need of answering again. let's know if it works @juliette

Comment: @Obumuneme Nwabude: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .fa-chevron-down{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

this code will remove your icon

but about the text

NO

Please do not make font-size smaller, this is a wrong approach to making websites responsive. In Responsive Web Design as your device size decreases you should generally increase  your sizes(absolutely there are a few exceptions but generally that's true)

because the device size is Already Small Enough!

consider yourself trying to use this page with a device with below 400px width, is it easier to read smaller texts on that site? or larger ones? is it easier to TAP on smaller buttons? or larger ones (With enough distance)

so I suggest you increase the size of your side-bar instead of decreasing your font-size

Comment: @ObumunemeNwabude  Thanks for your edit, it's much better now

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried `.iconClass { display: none; }`, but the icon is still there? [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-cdyhsj?file=src/styles.css).

Comment: no I was wrong about it's class name, try out ```.fa-chevron-down``` instead of ```.iconClass```